# How to aproximate matches in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query in my API right now:

```
{
"query": {
           "multi_match": {
               "query": event, //this is send by the API
               "fields": ["company", "location"]
            }
         }
}
```

If I write a partial search like "chi" for example, I get 0 hits unless I write a full word like "china". I tried the wildcards according to the elastic search, however, what I want to achieve is that if I write "Chi" I should get for example "china" or "Chile" since they both match. I want the same for any other partial matches. I thought wildcards would do the trick but they didn't.

How do I match partial queries in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with query_string

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "query": "*chi*",
        "fields": ["company", "location"]
    }
}
```